# Access files located in root of WAR file from ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-listeners

I have a `.war` file. And I need access to file located inside `ROOT_OF_WAR/someFolder/myfile.txt`

How I can access to it using `ServletContextListener`?

Does `ContextClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(resourceName)` point to root of web-app (i.e. root of`.war` file)?

Or I need to access it using `ServletContextEvent#getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("someFolder/myfile.txt");` ?

Comment: AFAIK, you need the latter one - why don't you just try it?

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883861/how-to-access-a-file-under-web-inf-folder-in-java-class has a lot of good information.

Answer (score 4):

```
ServletContext context = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();    
File file = new File(context.getRealPath("/someFolder/myFile.txt"));
```

That is all you need. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: `getServletContext()` method is undefined for type `ServletContextListener`. I can get it only from `ServletContextEvent#getServletContext()` - but it will still work? I have some concerns about it.

Comment: Why don't you try and see? :)

Comment: It very long history.. I need to redeploy whole app. It not 5 min, it about 20 mins'

Comment: I am using: new File(context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/jdbc/hibernate.cfg.xml")) to get the hibernate cfg file. And it works perfectly. It is also in the ServletContextListener