# How to access a file under WEB-INF folder in java class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a plain java class in a web application and want to read a configuration file under `WEB-INF` folder. I know the way to access the file if its in the classpath (`WEB-INF/classes` folder). Since `WEB-INF/classes` folder is meant for `.class` files, I want to keep my configuration file under `WEB-INF` folder only.

Can anyone tell me how I can access it from my java class?

Comment: If the configuration file is for the Java classes, why put it in the `WEB-INF` folder... why not in the `src/main/resources` folder and access it from there?

Comment: I would say that `getResourceAsStream` should work

Comment: The configuration should be in src/main/resources, and will be built into class folder when deploy the web app. Why do you need to put the configuration file into WEB-INF folder?

Comment: I (tentatively) agree with @Thinhbk: the WEB-INF is a location for configuration for web-related components, like servlets and filters. Configuration for 'plain Java class' components should be on the classpath. Maybe.

Comment: I feel `WEB-INF/classes` folder should not contain any configuration files.

Answer (score 22):

[ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) will load a file from a given path relative to the root of the WAR file. Something like:

```
ServletContext ctx;
InputStream configStream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.properties");
```

The major issue here is that you need access to the servlet context to be able to do this. You have that in a servlet or a filter, but not in a non-web component further back in the application. You have a few options:

- Make the servlet context available from the web layer to the service layer, via an application-scoped variable, or injection, or some other way
- Put the resource-loading code in the web layer, and expose that to the service layer
- Load the configuration in the web layer, and pass it on to the service layer

Comment: No direct way of doing this in non-web component like plain java class?

Comment: Not that i know of. A plain Java class has no idea it's part of a web application, so there's no way it could have access to any API for doing things specific to web applications!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the absolute path of servlet using `getRealPath()` method of `ServletContext` and then append `WEB-INF` to the path you get. I think this is very basic there may be some other answers as well.

Comment: I know how to do this with the help of `ServletContext`. But what I am looking for is to do this in a plain java class.

Answer (score 1):

`hey you all care for context related file loading like application context , web.xml ,config and property file`

Here is how to load a java file any kind of file under `WEB-INF` but it stored on another stucture like a sub folder `reportFile` the your file or sub folder again `report01`--

`fullpath is = /WEB-INF/reportFile/report01/report.xml` ,i have tried many possibilities to load and read this xml file ...none of the above worked for me but , here is the trick for future use...

`In Action or inservice class you know interface implementation class` no `imports` that is good part also.

## declare your file object

```
File myClass = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile());
System.out.println("Finding calss path first then remove classes from the path "    + myClass.getCanonicalPath().replaceFirst("classes", "")+"reportFIle/report01/reports.xml")
```

## 2.Load the path by removing `classes` from the above and add your specific path

```
File f = new File(myClass.getCanonicalPath().replaceFirst("classes", "")+"reportFile/report01/reports.xml")
```

## Then

you can even parse it using xml parser or do anything

```
document = docBuilder.parse(new File(myClass.getCanonicalPath().replaceFirst("classes", "")+"reportFile/report01/reports.xml"));
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

"new FIleInputStream(
      Utility.class.getClassLoader().getResource(keyFileName).getPath()
)" 
worked for me.

Here "Utility" is my class name where the code is calling this line , "keyFileName" is the file i need to open