# Insert a header image in JSF Page

Tags: java, jsf

I'm new in JSF

I want to insert a header image in JSF Page

I'm using

```
img src="WEB-INF/ressources/header.jpg" width="1250" height="181" alt="header"
```

Note: ressources is the folder where images exists

But header image is not displaying.

Comment: please post complete code

Comment: Don't work :(  inside header or inside body

Comment: You spelled `resources` wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header.jpg` needs to be out of WEB-INF folder. Try moving the file in `WebContent/resources` folder, and changing the code as :

```
img src="/resources/header.jpg" width="1250" height="181" alt="header"
```

Files present in WEB-INF folder cannot be directly accessed from the browser.

If you still want to keep the image in WEB-INF folder, create a servlet with code as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12884183/960778). This servlet should in response return the image. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623747/960778)

Comment: it wooooooorked thank youuuuu :D