# Servlet can't output HashMap keys to jsp: FileNotFoundException, util class can't find local file after deployment

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a `TranslateServlet` that takes some text, creates an instance of a `Cracker` class and calls a `getCrackedResult` method which returns a `HashMap` of keys and values:

```
public class TranslateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cracker cracker = new Cracker("German", "English");
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Cracker.EntrySet<String, ArrayList<String>>>> crackedResults =
                cracker.getCrackedResult("Ich bin");

        for (String category: crackedResults.keySet())  {
            System.out.print(category);  //works fine
        }

    }


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Cracker cracker = new Cracker("German", "English");

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Cracker.EntrySet<String, ArrayList<String>>>> crackedResults =
                cracker.getCrackedResult("Ich bin");

        for (String category: crackedResults.keySet())  {
                response.getWriter().print(category);  //doesn't work
        }

        response.getWriter().print("DONE");  //works fine
    }
}
```

However, while iterating over a `HashMap` inside the `main` method works fine, when trying to get the key values through `doPost()` method, I only get `DONE` as an output, and no other values. Why??

**EDIT:** "Doesn't work" means doesn't output categories. If the main method outputs "Dog", "Cat", the jsp page only outputs "Done", instead of "Dog", "Cat", "Done".

What is wrong with my question to suffice closing it? Thank you anonymous downvoter too.

**EDIT**: I checked the tomcat's log and there is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: some_folder/some_file.bin` error every time the servlet is called.

I realised that the function `getCrackedResult` makes use of a local file like this:

```
InputStream inputPOS = new FileInputStream("some_folder/some_file.bin");
```

I tried moving the file to `WEB-INF` and changing the file path:

```
InputStream inputPOS = new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/some_folder/some_file.bin");
```

But I still get the exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF/some_folder/some_file.bin`.

How should I deal with the file so that `Cracker` class, specifically its `getCrackedResults` function could get it after deployment. My file structure looks like this:

```
Project Root
------------src
---------------com
------------------util
----------------------Cracker.java
------------------web
---------------------TranslateServlet.java
------------target
------------------classes
-------------------------com
----------------------------util
--------------------------------Cracker.class
----------------------------web
-------------------------------TranslateServlet.class
------------imgs
------------some_folder
-----------------------some_file.bin
------------WEB-INF
-------------------classes
-------------------lib
-------------------some_folder
------------------------------some_file.bin (tried putting it here)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your question is that it isn't complete. No `Cracker` class.

Comment: The title doesn’t fit what your code is doing. The normal approach would be to have the servlet set request attributes and let the JSP get them from the request.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes That's what I initially did. But in trying to get to the root of the problem I tried the servlet output the `HashMap` directly which didn't work, meaning the problem is somewhere in the servlet inself.

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at runtime. You need to place it and access it as a resource, not as a file.

Comment: to make it work, (try) put it under `WEB-INF/classes/some_folder/some_file.bin` ...and then refer to  `new FileInputStream("some_folder/some_file.bin");` ...if that doesn't load `...ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/some_folder/some_file.bin");` could.

Comment: @xerx593 The first one won't work, the second one will.

Comment: *best* would be `request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path)`, where path starts with "/" and is relatively to your servlet context root (the root of your .war ..the folder "deployed" above "WEB-INF") ..answer!?;) ...then you *could* put it *above* WEB-INF, which i would still **not** recommend.

Comment: @xerx593 I tried the `InputStream inputPOS = Cracker.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some_folder/some_file.bin")`, but it seems the `InputStream` is null, because I get a `NullPointerException`. Tried it with both `"some_folder/some_file.bin"` and `"WEB-INF/some_folder/some_file.bin"` as arguments. Tried putting the `/` in front of both paths as well, same result.

Comment: @xerx593 You would still not recommend why?

Comment: @parsecer You didn't copy his code correctly. Note 'where `path` starts with "/"'.

Comment: @user207421 "Tried putting the / in front of both paths as well, same result".

Comment: @user207421 The resource is under `Project Root/some_folder/some_file.bin` (and now that I've copied it, it's in `Project Root/WEB-INF/some_folder/some_file.bin` as well).

Comment: Why? That's not where you were told to put it. Why post the question if you're going to just ignore what you're being told here?

Comment: I followed @xerx593 comment. As far as I can see, they didn't mention moving the file anywhere else.

Comment: No you didn't. @xerx593 has said to use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` or `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream`. You have used neither. You have also not followed his suggested resource placement in either case. He certainly did mention moving it elsewhere. Twice.

Comment: ..not recommend: because the file (some.bin) is exposed to "the web", WEB-INF folder is protected (no1 can "download" your web.xml;). `Cracker.class.getClassLoader()`...is not (always) good in servlet environment, alternative: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/relatively/to/WEB-INF/classes")` ..and best: (there are several ways to obtain the servletcontext) `... ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/where-ever-you-put-it/some.bin")`

Comment: @xerx593 You appear to suggest that you are not recommending `ServletConext.getResourceAsStream()`, in the comment where you introduced it.

Comment: Nono, I *recommend* `ServletConext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/some_folder/some.bin")` :) , and the file must be there. (in .war)

Comment: "This method is different from java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream, which uses a class loader. This method **allows servlet containers to make a resource available to a servlet from any location, without using a class loader**." from [servletContext-javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)

Comment: aah, **not recommend**: placing sensible files outside WEB-INF! xD

Comment: possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12883861/592355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

Please deploy(!) `/WEB-INF/some_file/some.bin` at the correct location, then you can access its `FileInputStream` from a servlet environment like:

```
java.io.InputStream inS = /*httpRequest.get*/servletContext
    .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/some_file/some.bin");
```

See: [ServletContext Javadoc (Java8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/8/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I managed to fix it with

```
InputStream inputPOS = Cracker.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some_folder/some_file.bin");
```

solution **and** placing `some_folder/some_file.bin` **both** inside

1. `Project Root/target/classes` (so that code would work inside IDE)

**and**

2. `Project Root/WEB-INF/classes` (so that code would work when deployed on tomcat).